# Appending to read-only text box with different colors

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I can easily append to the read-only text box but my problem is switching colors depending on which if statement is being executed:

```
foreach (var attribute in elements)
{
    if (File.Exists(pathtocheck))
    {
       outputLOG.AppendText("blah blah blah");
    } 
    else 
    {
       outputLOG.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
       outputLOG.AppendText("blah blah blah");
    }
}
```

GOAL: If filepath exists use black text and if it doesn't then use red text.  My code above currently uses all black or all red, I want it to alternate depending on the situation.

Comment: what framework? ASP.NET, WPF, WinForms?

Comment: framework is .net 4.0 and its on winforms

Comment: You need control that capable of multi-color or do custom draw. With winforms text box "as is" you're out of luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard TextBox control does not support multi-colored text (Rich-Text formatting). You will need a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control or something similar.